# How scrape a website in which i post information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape announcements information from the https://nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=allAnnouncements.
Specifically i want to goto Corporate information tab on left hand side of website and then open the link of corporate announcements under equities.
After that i want to post information of certain equity symbol in text box and download the output through the export csv link on left hand side of the page.

I am struggling to understand how to first navigate to this particular page since all the pages have the same url https://nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=allAnnouncements.
I have been trying to use inspect network in chrome to know how do i navigate to particular page from the above link. After doing some research on network tab

[image: Actual Webpage where to navigate].

[image: Inspecting the Network to figure out the link].

Need to know how to request it.

I am expecting script to navigate to particular page and then post information of symbols to download announcements csv link

Comment: `requests.post(...)`

Comment: show your code and full error message (full Traceback).

Comment: Before writing the code i need to know first how do i reach this webpage. I don't know first what to request in the code

Comment: this page use JavaScript (AJAX/XHR) to get data and change content - so it doesn't change url. `requests` and `BS` doesns't run JavaScript so you can't get it directly from page - or you would have to use `Selenium` which can control web browser which will run JavaScript.

Comment: if you find url which JavaScript use to get data then you can use `reuqests` with this url. Mostly JavaScript use data in JSON format which you can easily convert to Python's dictionary and get what you need from dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You found good url. It gives data in JSON format. But this JSON has some mistakes and standard module `json` can't read it. With module `dirtyjson` I can read it.

```
import requests
#import json
import dirtyjson

url = 'https://nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/getAnnouncements.jsp?period=Latest%20Announced'

r = requests.get(url)
#data = r.json() # doesn't work because JSON data has some mistakes

#text = r.text.strip()
#print(text)
#data = json.loads(text) # doesn't work because JSON data has some mistakes

data = dirtyjson.loads(r.text)
#print(data)

for item in data['rows']:
    #print(item)
    print(item.keys())
    print(item['sym'])
    print(item['desc'])
    print(item['name'])
    print(item['date'][:2], item['date'][2:4], item['date'][4:8])
```

Some results:

```
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
MOTOGENFIN
Updates
The Motor & General Finance Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
KANORICHEM
Address Change
Kanoria Chemicals & Industries Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
JAIHINDPRO
Updates
Jaihind Projects Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
BLUECHIP
Appointment
Blue Chip India Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
BLUECHIP
Resignation
Blue Chip India Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
JAIHINDPRO
Corporate Insolvency Resolution Process
Jaihind Projects Limited
21 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
PAEL
Updates
PAE Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
BANDHANBNK
Updates
Bandhan Bank Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
ALICON
Updates
Alicon Castalloy Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
ADANIENT
Acquisition
Adani Enterprises Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
NLCINDIA
Updates
NLC India Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
SHILPAMED
Updates
Shilpa Medicare Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
KOTHARIPRO
Code of Conduct under SEBI(PIT) Reg., 2015
Kothari Products Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
LEEL
Updates
LEEL Electricals Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
SHILPAMED
Updates
Shilpa Medicare Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
ATULAUTO
Updates
Atul Auto Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
PDPL
Resignation
Parenteral Drugs (India) Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
IDBI
Updates
IDBI Bank Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
BLBLIMITED
Updates
BLB Limited
20 04 2019
['sym', 'desc', 'Ind', 'ISIN', 'name', 'date', 'seqId']
BLBLIMITED
Shareholders meeting
BLB Limited
20 04 2019
```